# Connection Raspberry Pi and Mac using PyCharmEdu

Tags: python, pi-3b+

I am a new Raspberry Pi user.

I want to run my code that is written in MacBookPro, on Raspberry Pi. In other words, I write my code in my MacBookPro (by using PyCharmEdu ide) and run ıt on Raspberry Pi which connected to my computer.

First question is: Is it possible? if yes Second question is : How can I do?

I know it is a bit board question so any link that explain how, will be appreciated.

PS1 : I have already checked many blogs and and videos but I could not find a answer.
PS2 : My second step will be make a cluster so if you have answer for pi cluster (I can buy few more raspberry pi and) jump to that problem.
PS3 : I thought this a programming problem so I firstly asked at stackoverflow.

Comment: The duplicate contains some generic options for remote development.  PyCharm I would assume has some potential for remote execution -- first you have to find out whether that is true (which is not a Pi related question).  If not, then those generic alternatives (essentially, remote mounting a file share) are what you have.  If so, then you want to research the question in a *linux*, not Pi, context.  The exception to this would be if PyCharm or some jetbrains component needs to be installed on the remote system -- this would be find on x86(-64) linux systems but not the pi.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you mean Python.

Yes, you can run Python on the Pi.

Python 2 and Python 3 are supported.

Copy your code to a file on the Pi.  I'll assume your code is called my_code.py.

To run it use either

For Python 2

```
python my_code.py
```

For Python 3

```
python3 my_code.py
```

Comment: What I understand is you explain how I can run a python code which located in Pi, in Pi. However I want to learn it is possible to write (specificly in PyCharmEdu ide) a code in my Mac and run it in Pi.